# What wrong in this scala code

Tags: scala

This function should give back the sum of all the numbers in the list but when I run it I always get back `ans=0`.

```
def sum(st: List[Int]): Int = {
  var ans=0 

  def combine(st: List[Int], ans:Int): Int = {
    if (st.isEmpty) ans else combine(st.tail, ans)        
  }
  ans
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking for, but just for the record, you can also call `st.sum` and get your result.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the head of the list to `ans`. At the moment you're recursing but not actually using the head of the list.

e.g. I think you need something like the below, in which you add the head of the list to the sum of the remainder.

```
scala> def sum(st: List[Int]): Int = 
     | {
     | if (st.isEmpty) {
     |    0
     | }
     | else {
     |    st.head + sum(st.tail)
     | }
     | }
sum: (st: List[Int])Int
```

Comment: Also, it would probably help to _call_ combine :)

Answer (score 3):

1) You're not calling the inner method combine - you are just returning ans as it is iniatilized to 0.

2) combine doesn't really do anything

I think the code you wanted to write was the following:

```
def sum(st: List[Int]): Int = {
  def combine(st: List[Int], ans:Int): Int = {
    if (st.isEmpty) ans else combine(st.tail, ans + st.head)        
  }
  combine(st, 0)
}
```

but of course a shorter version would be:

```
st.foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
```

or just

```
st.sum
```

which uses a standard type class instance of Numeric: IntIsIntegral:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric$$IntIsIntegral$

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a method `combine` inside your method `sum`, but you are not calling `combine` (other than within `combine`, so it never gets called). If you don't call the method, it will not be executed; just defining the method doesn't mean it's executed.

If you want to program in the functional style, you should also avoid using mutable variables (`var`); use immutable values (`val`) instead.

Also, your `combine` method is not summing anything (it's not modifying `ans` anywhere, or using any value in the list).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Brian answer on why your solution does not work.

Moreover, there is an even shorter way to do it with the API of Sequence of Scala (which List implements), using foldLeft :

```
def sum(st: List[Int]): Int = {
    st.foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

foldLeft, and even better, sum are the preferred option as hedefalk mentioned.